# Modify table to get absolute Frequency and relative Frequency

Tags: r, statistics, frequency, absolute

I would like to display the absolute frequency and the relative frequency in a table.

#### What I get:

```
female   male 

314    577

[1] 891

[1] 0.352413

[1] 0.647587
```

#### What I want (Whitespaces doesnt work so I divided it with |):

```
Sex | absolute Frequency | relative Frequency

male | 577 | 0.647587

female | 314 | 0.352413
```

**Code:**

```
table(titanic$Sex)
length(titanic$Sex)
length(which(titanic$Sex == "female")) / length(titanic$Sex)
length(which(titanic$Sex == "male")) / length(titanic$Sex)
```

Comment: There are several packages with a `titanic` (lower case `t`) dataset. Which one are you using? Take a look at `prop.table`.

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(titanic) 

df <- data.frame(table(titanic_train$Sex)) %>%
  mutate(Rel_Freq = Freq/sum(Freq)) %>%
  rename(Sex=Var1)
df
```

Output is:

```
     Sex Freq Rel_Freq
1 female  314 0.352413
2   male  577 0.647587
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

First, count the number of females and males and convert the result to a data.frame

```
result <- as.data.frame(table(titanic$Sex))
```

Second, calculate the relative frequency by dividing by the number of rows and add it to the data.frame.

```
result$rel_freq <- result$Freq/nrow(titanic)
```

Last, you can optionally change the column names to the exact ones in your example.

```
colnames(result) <- c('Sex',  'absolute Frequency', 'relative Frequency')
```

But maybe there is a more fancy way?